# pass setState from parent to its child component using React Hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How do I pass setState from parent to its child component using React Hooks? Code is provided:

### App.js

```
export default App() {
  <Main>
    <Widget/>
  </Main>
}
```

### Main.js

```
export default Main() {
  const [marketProducts, setMarketProducts] = useState([]);
  ...
  return 
    <DataContext.Provider value={marketProducts}>
      ...
      {props.children}
    </DataContext.Provider>;
}
```

### Widget.js

```
export default Widget() {
  return <div>
    <NavComponent/>
    ...
  </div>
}
```

### NavComponent.js

```
export default NavComponent() {
  // need setMarketProducts here but not sure how to bring from Main.js to here
  return <div>
    ...
  </div>
}
```

Comment: I think it's not directly possible in this setup. I would suggest bubbling up your "setMarketProducts" hook, to be in App.js or put <Widget> component also in the Main.js class, so you can pass the hook there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass the `setMarketProducts` to you `DataContext` the same way you passed the `marketProducts`. Export `Datacontext` form Main.js. Although I suggest to create seprate file for your context

```
export default Main(props) {
  const [marketProducts, setMarketProducts] = useState([]);
  ...
  return 
    <DataContext.Provider value={marketProducts, setMarketProducts}>
      ...
      {props.children}
    </DataContext.Provider>;
}
```

Then use `useContext` hook in NavComponent.js to access `setMarketProducts`

```
import { DataContext } from 'Main'
...
export default Widget() {
  
  const { setMarketProducts } = React.useContext(DataContext)

  return <div>
    ...
  </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass setMarketProducts down the chain as shown in example below. Other wise you can use some kind of store e.g. useContext or redux

```
export default App() {
  const [marketProducts, setMarketProducts] = useState([]);
  <Main setMarketProducts={setMarketProducts} marketProducts={marketProducts}>
    <Widget setMarketProducts={setMarketProducts}/>
  </Main>
}

export default Main({ setMarketProducts,marketProducts, ...props }) {

  ...
  return 
    <DataContext.Provider value={marketProducts}>
      ...
      {props.children}
    </DataContext.Provider>;
}


export default Widget({ setMarketProducts }) {
  return <div>
    <NavComponent setMarketProducts={setMarketProducts}/>
    ...
  </div>
}

export default NavComponent({ setMarketProducts }) {
  // need setMarketProducts here but not sure how to bring from Main.js to here
  return <div>
    ...
  </div>
}
```